# node-gyp configure error incorrect header check

Tags: node.js, npm

when install socket.io using npm i got this error..gyp configure error incorrect header check.and i have installed node-gyp and set python parameter also..

```
   python version -2.7
   node version   -0.12.5
   npm version -2.11.2
```

```
> utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install /home/local/PAYODA/murugesan.p/Desktop/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: incorrect header check
gyp ERR! stack     at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:366:17)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/local/PAYODA/murugesan.p/Desktop/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 

> bufferutil@1.1.0 install /home/local/PAYODA/murugesan.p/Desktop/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: incorrect header check
gyp ERR! stack     at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:366:17)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/local/PAYODA/murugesan.p/Desktop/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.1.0
```